# Select JTabbedPane Panel with JMenuItem

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, jmenuitem, pane

I have a menu-bar and a tabbed pane in a frame, and i want that if i select a menuitem, then the requested tab will open. Please help me with this, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ActionListener` of the `JMenuItem`, you can call [`JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

like SoboLAN said:

```
    final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabs.add("title", panel);
    //add more tabs...

    // here the important part starts
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("open tab 1");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //this function get called when you click the item.
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //insert the index you want to select
            tabs.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
    });
```